# Failed audit for answer that was deleted and posted again

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I failed this audit on the low quality queue today: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10710088

At first I was confused because the answer seems high quality going into great detail about how to fix the problem asked in the question. I clicked through to the question: [Linkedin Login android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280864/linkedin-login-android) and found that the answer was still there and had an upvote.

However, it seems like the answer in the audit was from last week and was deleted by the owner, then reposted by the same person a few days later.

Should this still count as an audit question when it was deleted and reposted?

Comment: Timeline: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9rEws.png Partial history: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IiqOT.png Also, I rolled the deleted answer back to the state before the complete rewrite turning it into a maybe (I don't know) good answer, but nearly certainly an acceptable one. Thus, it can stay an audit (unless that throws it out).

Comment: @Deduplicator Wait, you made (deleted) content *worse* so it would be a better audit?  That seems ... bad.  (Yes, it was a copy/paste of the same posters other answer, but still...)

Comment: @Yakk: Think about it a bit more, and you'll see that reverting the deleted post to the state which justly earned it condemnation, while leaving the upvoted copy of the fixed post alone, is, *in balance*, the best thing for SO and everyone that could be done, as it was reposted. Yes, it's a curious situation for sure ;-)

Comment: @deduplicator The problem isn't that this is a bad audit.  It is with the system that selected it as a bad audit.  Making it a "good audit" by making it a bad post fixes almost nothing.

Comment: @Yakk: Rolling back to that state fixes what I could fix. What changes to the audit-selection-criteria would you propose? (Not sure what the current criteria actually are, though they naturally fall afool of GIGO.)

Comment: @Deduplicator substantially edited posts where the substantial edit was after the downvotes that made it appear low-quality are not good audit candidates.

Comment: @Yakk: Sure. And it should be possible to capture that somehow in the algorithm. Might make a good answer and/or FR. BTW: I already linked images of the relevant part of the timeline / revision-history.